# Coldfusion after use query group, how to count the total rows?

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfquery datasource="go_green" name="rank_community">
    SELECT area AS my_location FROM GREENTEAM_USERS order by area
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="rank_community" group="my_location">
    <tr leader-board-community  >
        <td leaderboard-counter></td>
        <td align="left">#my_location#</td>
        <td align="left">#???????#</td>                 
    </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

how can I get the total number of the rows after using query group?
I tried listlen(#my_location#), but it all shows 1...

Answer (score 2):

Rank_community.recordcount will give you the total number of rows.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain my question clear. I want to show the rows number for each group, not the total number.

Answer (score 1):

With the specific code in your question, all you need to do is add the count to your query.

```
<cfquery datasource="go_green" name="rank_community">
    SELECT area AS my_location 
    , count(area) area_count
    FROM GREENTEAM_USERS 
    group by area
    order by my_location
</cfquery>
```

If you are doing other things with your output, you could do something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="rank_community" group="my_location">
<cfset area_count = 0>
more grouped data code
<cfoutput>
<cfset area_count++>
more ungrouped data code
</cfoutput>
#my_location# occurs #area_count# times
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `currentRow` attribute.

Example:

```
<cfoutput query="QueryName" group="Group">
  #my_location# - #currentrow#
</cfoutput>
```

If you're grouping, however, you may need to use nested outputs depending on what you want your final result to look like.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain my question clear. I want to show the rows number for each group, not the total number.